# CruiseControl.Net - not able to see Project Statistics

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I've made a reinstallation of the buildserver and can no longer see the standard graphs of project statistics. The error message shown is

"Missing/Invalid statistics reports. Please check if you have enabled the Statistics Publisher, and statistics have been collected atleast once after that."

To the best of my knowledge, the ccnet.config file has not been changed in this respect and by inspection it is verified that I have a Statistics / statisticsList-section for the project. Furthermore, the values appear in the Artifacts\statistics.csv and Artifacts\report.xml files.

My guess would then be StatisticsGraph.xslt, which I have copied fresh from distribution to both Server\xlst and WebDashboard\xslt (why are they located in both places, by the way!?). Rebuild and check - still same error message.

Any hints to how to debug this would be appreciated!

Comment: which version (original and reinstallation)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Statistics report is somewhat tricky. Forget about `statistics.csv`. `report.xml` is the file you should take a closer look at.

`report.xml` contains header elements and `n` value rows. If the header elements and the row content do not match, no results are displayed at all.

The only advice I can give at the moment: Perhaps you should take a look at [that](http://www.codeplex.com/ccstatistics). I haven't tried it myself and it might be outdated and not extremly reliable, but it targets the problem.

Comment: I got it to work by reapplying the entire set of configuration files from the installation package. Not exactly satisfying, but it did the trick.